# Is there a way to search webelement on a main window first, if not found, then start searching inside iframes?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Requirement: Bydefault, search for webelement on main window, if found perform action else search for webelement inside iframes and perform required action

Selenium 3.141

```
'''
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'here')]"));
    boolean displayFlag = el.isDisplayed();
    if(displayFlag == true)
    {
    sysout("element available in main window")  
    el.click();
    }
    else 
    {
      for(int f=0;f<10;f++)
      {
          sysout("element available in frameset")  
          switchToFrame(frameName[f]);
          el.click();
          System.out.println("Webelement not displayed");
      }
    }
'''
```

My script is failing at first line itself. It is trying to find element in main window but element is actually available in iframe.

But the requirement is to search first in main window and then only navigate to iframes. How to handle such usecase?

Any suggestion would be helpful? Thank you.

Comment: search WebElements instead of WebElement and if you find zero WebElements call your method to serch WebElement(s) in iFrame.

Comment: List<WebElement> elementsOutOfFrame = driver.findElements(By.LOCATOR); Int x = elementsOutOfFrame.size(); if (x == 0) { driver.switchToFrame... }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can write a loop to go through all the iframes if the element not present in the main window.
**Java Implementation:**

```
 if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath goes here").size()==0){
     int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
     for(int iFrameCounter=0; iFrameCounter<=size; iFrameCounter++){
        driver.switchTo().frame(iFrameCounter);
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath goes here").size()>0){
            System.out.println("found the element in iframe:" + Integer.toString(iFrameCounter));
            // perform the actions on element here
        }
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
 }
```

**Python Implementation**

```
# switching to parent window - added this to make sure always we check on the parent window first
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# check if the elment present in the parent window
if (len(driver.finds_element_by_xpath("xpath goes here"))==0):
    # get the number of iframes
    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    # iterate through all iframes to find out which iframe the required element
    for iFrameNumber in iframes:
        # switching to iframe (based on counter)
        driver.switch_to.frame(iFrameNumber+1)
        # check if the element present in the iframe
        if len(driver.finds_element_by_xpath("xpath goes here")) > 0:
            print("found element in iframe :" + str(iFrameNumber+1))
            # perform the operation here
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: This is a bit complex solution, pretty nice for pages with lots of iFrames. Thx for putting it here, I'll surely use it.